# Bitcoind daemon: error connecting to the server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, daemon

I am trying to create a new bitcoin address and store it in a shell variable $NEW_ADDRESS.

When I run this command:

```
$NEW_ADDRESS=$(./bitcoin-cli getnewaddress)
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332
Make sure the bitcoind server is running and that you are connecting to the correct RPC port.
-bash: =: command not found
```

I have tried everything to fix the connection error, including typing the command:

```
./bitcoind -rpcport=8332
```

Or even, changing the bitcoin config:

```
nano ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

And typing these lines on the configuration:

```
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332;
```

But nothing works. Does anyone have an idea on how to troubleshoot and fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `ps aux | grep bitcoind` is the process running?

Answer (score 1):

> -bash: =: command not found

Leave out the initial dollar symbol when you assign the variable:

`NEW_ADDRESS=$(./bitcoin-cli getnewaddress)`

Use the dollar symbol when you use the variable:

`echo $NEW_ADDRESS`